# QueryDSL query translate full outer join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, querydsl

I'm doing a query with QueryDSL but when the query is translated to MySQL the resulting sql contains a full outer join and an exception is thrown

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join ....
```

How can I tell QueryDSL not to create full outer join statements?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet to show what you are doing?